# Enclose specific words with single quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm after a simple solution to quote text in a string with quotes.

For example:

```
DATEDIFF(Minutes, Lead.WhenCreated, @Today)
```

need to be updated to

```
DATEDIFF(Minutes, Lead.WhenCreated, '@Today')
```

If the source string is already has quotes for the token then no change should be made.  There may be multiple tokens in the string and I won't know what the token value will be - only to say that it will start with the @ character.

My environment is Visual Studio C# 2008.

Hope some can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern:

```
(?<!')(@\w+)
```

Replacement:

```
'$1'
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey,  this also works in addition to FailedDev's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(@\b\w+\b)", "'$1'");
```

You can use this one. It will find all words that start with @ and add quotes to them.

Edit :

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"((?<!')@\b\w+\b)", "'$1'");
```

To account for already quoted strings.

Comment: One small problem, if the source string does contain quotes( eg. DATEDIFF(Hours, Lead.WhenCreated, '@Today') ) then the replacement still takes place i.e. the result is: DATEDIFF(Hours, Lead.WhenCreated, ''@Today'')

Answer (score 0):

It look like you're building a SQL statement in C# code and then replacing the parameters yourself. You are probably better off using this method...

```
DataReader rdr;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MY_CONNECTIONSTRING)
{
    con.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(Minutes, Lead.WhenCreated, @Today) FROM tbl";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Today", datDateValue);
         rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

This method is safer against malicious SQL Injection.

[This is an article addressing the issue in C#](http://en.csharp-online.net/ASP.NET_Security_Hacks%E2%80%94Avoiding_SQL_Injection)

Comment: Hi El Ronnoco, I understand your point but all the replacement will be performed by the database server as the sql will be run by a scheduler (i.e. at an undetermined time) - so the actual value will not be known until the SQL is executed.  Point taken about SQL Injection, I'm familiar with this but will also check out your link.

Comment: @J Dubs I figured your application was probably inherently injection safe however its a good habit to get into, for example your code may be copied out into a WebService or Web Application by someone else and before you know it, bing-bada-boom, [little bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) is trashing your backend :)